# Any dynamic way to use "using" statement in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, using, pester

I'm having issues with the using statement which can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-7). This statement (unlike `Import-Module`) is required in order to get an actual class definition from a PowerShell module. I have a use case for this because I need the class definition itself for Pester unit testing.

**The problem is I can't find any way to provide the module path dynamically.** I'm unable to use variables like `$PSScriptPath` in the path. I'm only able to provide it with a absolute path or a relative path. Neither of these really work for me.

- *Absolute path:* Issue here is unit tests will be run on different machines (build servers). Therefore, having a hardcoded absolute path from a dev machine isn't an option.
- *Relative path:* This also is problematic, since unit tests are triggered from a base directory which then run all Test files recursively. So I would have to `Set-Location` to specific directories for each test in order for relative paths to function. To tests dozens of modules, this is a lot of overhead to have to manage when I should be able to just run all my unit tests without this hassle.

Is there a better way I can manage this? General directory structure is like this...

```
src
   project1
      someModule1
         someModule1.psm1
      someModule2
         someModule2.psm1
      someModule3
         someModule3.psm1
      tests
         someModule1.Tests.ps1
         someModule2.Tests.ps1
         someModule3.Tests.ps1
```

From `src` directory, run `Invoke-Pester -Script .` to run all unit test files. The "Tests" files need to be able to import classes from their corresponding modules. Worse yet, I'm not getting any errors when the `using` statement doesn't find the module path unless I run the using statement interactively in the console. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are the modules installed properly in a PSmodule path?

Are the modules installed. If so you can get the path to them by querying:

```
(Get-Module -Name someModulex -ListAvailable).ModuleBase
```